# Gift of Metallic Dragon Protective Wings duration

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, reactions, duration

How long do the protective wings from the feat Gift of the Metallic Dragon last?
The description of the Gift of the Metallic Dragon feat provided in the *Fizban's Treasury of Dragons* sourcebook states, in part (my emphasis):

> **Protective Wings**. You can manifest protective wings that can shield you or others. When you or another creature you can see within 5 feet of you is hit by an attack roll, you can use your reaction to manifest spectral wings from your back **for a moment**. You grant a bonus to the target’s AC equal to your proficiency bonus against that attack roll, potentially causing it to miss. You can use this reaction a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.

Answer (score 10):

### “Against that attack”

The bonus to AC is for the triggering attack only, since the feature states:

> You grant a bonus to the target’s AC equal to your proficiency bonus **against that attack roll**

Since it doesn’t state that the bonus persists beyond “that attack”, it is good for “that attack” only.

Comment: Good lord, I read that thing 50 times. Thanks!

Comment: @Bryan No worries, it took me a few reads too.